# Formula for Feigenbaum’s constant?

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, approximation, conjectures, continued-fractions

I have conjectured a formula to calculate [the Feigenbaum constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FeigenbaumConstant.html) $\delta \approx 4.66920$.

> $\delta\stackrel{?}{=}$ $$4+\cfrac{1\times 2 -1}{1+\cfrac{2\times 3 -1}{2^2+\cfrac{3\times 4 -1}{1+\cfrac{4\times 5 -1}{3^2+\cfrac{5\times 6 - 1}{1+\ddots}}}}}$$ which after several iterations is $\approx 4.66919$ (I believe).

This discovery, whether exact or approximate, was completely accidental. Can this be numerically verified? Thanks.

Comment: What is the pattern of terms 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, ... in the numerators? Is it just the even numbers but with the 2 replaced by a 1?

Comment: @Rahul yes. It's the sequence $2+4+6+8+\cdots$ but then subtract $1$ from it. (It is a very interesting sequence for reasons about which I leave the reader to ponder.)

Comment: I see, so the $n$th numerator is $n(n+1)-1$.

Comment: @Rahul yes. I will write that instead for brevity. Thanks :)

Comment: I get the result $4.6691973410286147...$, so while it's close, it's not equal to the first Feigenbaum constant which is $4.669201609102…$.

Comment: @EinarRødland so close yet so far. I trust your result. Thanks for sharing and spending your time on my question. Apologies if any brute force techniques, if used, were inconvenient. At least I'm working on another infinite series now :)

Comment: @EinarRødland you should make that an answer.

Comment: Although not representing exactly the Feigenbaum constant (which would have been very surprising indeed), a nice continued fraction with a value surprisingly close (+1).

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, @Peter :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Python and the `sympy` library, I defined the following function to compute the continued fraction to arbitrary depth and precision:

```
def F(n, prec=100):
    x = sympy.Float(n+1, dps=prec)**2
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        x = 1 + (2*i*(2*i+1)-1)/x
        x = i*i + (2*i*(2*i-1)-1)/x
    return x+3
```

At 100 decimal precision, the continued fraction has stabilised at $n=300$ to
$$
4.669197341028614722501735076952905036174621190442756866058551504040545753015009110638731541739920174
$$
which is confirmed by increasing depth and precision further.

The [first Feigenbaum constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants) is $4.669201609102990671853203821578...$, so while the values are close, they are not the same.

---

For those not familiar with Python, `range(n,0,1)` counts down from $n$ to $1$. Arithmetic operations on `Float` objects are handled by the `Float` class even when the other value is an integer, which is why I don't need to explicitly convert `i` to a `Float` before computing with it.

The way the function works is it starts at the $2n$th term, ie the one that reads $(n+1)^2+\text{fraction}$ which it approximates to $(n+1)^2$ as a starting point, and then moves up one step at a time: two steps in each iteration.

Comment: The answer would benefit from mentioning somewhere "...so is not equal to the Feigenbaum constant"

Comment: @Wojowu: Good point. Will do that.

Comment: Thanks heaps, and congratulations! $(+1)$ $\color{green}{\checkmark}$